# How to show a loader untill on Js & CSS files loading using angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show a loader untill all css, js files are loaded. I want to do this using angularJs. Can anyone give me solutions for this problem ? How can detect all js, css files loaded using angularjs ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want a loader which should work for every $http call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution & it works for me.

```
angular.module().run(function(){
   angular.element(document).ready(function(){
       /* Loaders code will be here */
   })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Display you loader image initially and hide here

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    //Code to hide loader
});
```

Comment: This code will work on controller, so we need to load the controller. But I want this on configuration. So I am trying with -

    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        console.log("ALl contents loaded")
    });

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [this plugin.](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar) Angular-loading bar will show a loading bar until everythnig loads.